# Glom handling or skipping a PathError for data with different keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, glom

I am using the glom package to help with traversing a big dictionary.

Given this data:

```
data = {
    'groups': [
        {'instance': {'name': 'football'}},
        {'instance': {'name': 'rugby'}},
        {'id': 145, 'type': 'unknown'},
    ]
}
```

And using glom, I attempt to get the instance names:

```
import glom
instance_names = glom(data, ('groups', ['instance.name']))
```

I receive an Error:

```
glom.core.PathAccessError: could not access 'instance', part 0 of Path('instance', 'name'), got error: KeyError('instance')
```

How can I skip the objects where the `instance` key does not exist?

**Update**

I have tried to skip the exception but then I receive empty results:

```
instance_names = glom(data, ('groups', ['instance.name']), skip_exc=PathAccessError)
```

Comment: Just by the way with `yaql` this can be achieved with: `$.groups.where($.containsKey("instance"))`

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation of [`glom`](https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#glom.glom) API.

> `default (object)` – An optional default to return in the case an
>   exception, specified by `skip_exc`, is raised.
>
> `skip_exc` (Exception) – An
>   optional exception or tuple of exceptions to ignore and return `default`
>   (`None` if omitted). If `skip_exc` and default are both not set, glom

So

```
instance_names = glom(data, ('groups', ['instance.name']), skip_exc=PathAccessError)
```

will return the default(`None`) when it encounter `PathAccessError` Exception. Here is the [relevant part](https://github.com/mahmoud/glom/blob/master/glom/core.py#L1800-L1819) of the source code which explain this.

```
default = kwargs.pop('default', None if 'skip_exc' in kwargs else _MISSING)
skip_exc = kwargs.pop('skip_exc', () if default is _MISSING else GlomError)
...
...
try:
    ret = _glom(target, spec, scope)
except skip_exc:
    if default is _MISSING:
        raise
    ret = default
```

Here is one way you can solve this problem.

```
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from glom import glom, SKIP
>>>
>>> data = {
...     'groups': [
...         {'instance': {'name': 'football'}},
...         {'instance': {'name': 'rugby'}},
...         {'id': 145, 'type': 'unknown'},
...     ]
... }
>>>
>>> instance_names = glom(data, ('groups', [lambda x: glom(x, 'instance.name', default=SKIP)]))
>>> print(instance_names)
['football', 'rugby']
```

The [`SKIP` singleton](https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#glom.SKIP) can be returned from a function or included via a Literal to cancel assignment into the output object.